# Fullcalendar : disable specific event (Not whole calendar events)

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to disable specific event (Not whole calendar events) re-size.

For example, I have one demo external event drag to the calendar, I have put two different menu for drag event one is red colored and another is with green color. I have applied following flags for some of the specific features like.

```
eventOverlap: false,
editable: true,
disableResizing: true,
eventDurationEditable: false
```

Now what I need to do is, Is it possible to enable to re-size to a green colored event ?

Answer (score 1):

For events you wish to be resized, you can do so by adding property [**durationEditable** = **true**](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) to the event object:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  eventOverlap: false,
  editable: true,
  disableResizing: true,
  eventDurationEditable: false,
  events: [{
    title: 'Resize me',
    start: moment(),
    end: moment().add(75, 'minute'),
    durationEditable: true /* This event can be resized! */
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```